# NoReverseMatch Error- Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to build a Django project with multiple applications, hence using `urls.py` for each application. I encounter a `NoReverseMatch` error when Django tries to access the view.

Main **`urls.py`**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^intface/', intface),
    url(r'^', include("userapp.urls", namespace="userapp")),
]
```

**`userapp/urls.py`**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user.html"))
]
```

**`user.html`**:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url "userapp:user" %}" >
```

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/

Reverse for 'user' not found.
'user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Please help!

Comment: Try to update userapp urls.py with `url(r'^user/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user.html"), name='user')`
`

Comment: As an aside, it’s a good idea to use a dollar at the end of the regex, so that it matches `user/` but not `user/somethingelse`. Change it to `r'user/$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url "userapp:user" %}" >
```

In the line above when you say `userapp:user` it means the namespace = userapp and url_name = user.

You have done one thing right by setting the namespace in the following line:

```
url(r'^', include("userapp.urls", namespace="userapp")),
```

But you haven't set the url_name in this line:

```
url(r'^user/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user.html"))
```

So change the above line to the following line to set the name of the url:

```
url(r'^user/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user.html"), name="user")
```

Now your error should go away.

Answer (score 3):

userapp urls.py (add name):

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^user/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="user.html"), name='user')
]
```